# Is my after insert trigger efficient and safe to port to production?

Tags: bestpractice, update, after-trigger, insert, production

Recently I created an after insert trigger to update a field in my sponsorship object. it works so far in sandbox and has passed the unit test that I have created and has 100% code coverage. here is the code for the trigger:

```
trigger Donation_Updater on Opportunity (after insert) {
    For(Opportunity Don : Trigger.New)
    {
        if(Don.Sponsorship_Contract__c != null)
        {
            sponsorships__c spon =  [SELECT  Id FROM sponsorships__c WHERE Id = :Don.Sponsorship_Contract__c LIMIT 1];
    spon.Donation__c = Don.Id;
            update spon;
        }
        }
}
```

The question that I have is do you guys think this trigger is ready to be ported to production? The only thing i can think of is possibly replacing the SQOL statement  but I'd rather keep it in if at all possible,any other suggestions?

Comment: You absolutely need to move that query outside of the `for` loop and make this bulk safe. Presumably your unit test also doesn't operate on 200 Opportunities and their related sponsorships or you would have seen the exception that gets thrown by this pattern.

Answer (score 6):

No, you have not properly bulkified your code. Bulkification 101's most important lesson is to aggregate filter values, query before your loop and put records into a `Map`, and update values after your loop.

```
Set<Id> sponsorshipIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity record : trigger.new)
{
    sponsorshipIds .add(record.Sponsorship_Contract__c);
}
Map<Id, Sponsorships__c> sponsorships = new Map<Id, Sponsorships__c>([
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Id IN :sponsorshipIds
]);
```

However, in this case, *you do not need any query whatsoever*. You can update a record as long as you know its Id. Therefore, your code can be simplified to:

```
List<Sponsorships__c> sponsorships = new List<Sponsorships__c>();
for (Opportunity record : trigger.new)
{
    sponsorships.add(new Sponsorships__c(
        Id = record.Sponsorship_Contract__c,
        Donation__c = record.Id
    ));
}
update sponsorships;
```

Other things you should strongly consider are ***error handling*** and a ***handler pattern***. Another thing to note is you should always use ***singular names*** for your objects. If it's not too late, change `Sponsorships__c` to `Sponsorship__c`.

Comment: +1 for `Another thing to note is you should always use singular names for your objects` - this drives me nuts

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say this trigger is production ready. Couple of things I can recommend are.

- Move the  SOQL and DML outside for loop.
- Add error handling for SOQL and update.
- Do not write logic inside triggers.
- Read this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm) and Force.com enterprise architecture book if you have some time.
- Add comments about the functionality.(Personal choice)

Comment: sorry for the late response but I have a question. why should i not include logic within my trigger? without  my if statement an error is thrown if i try to make a donation that doesn't have a sponsor.

Comment: Well, simply put code should be well organized. Firstly, The logic in the trigger is not reusable. Secondly, you cannot implement record sharing in triggers. As you organisation becomes code heavy, the code should be well maintained and usually to do that we introduce layering. Think of a scenario where you have you logic in trigger and different developers want to modify the same trigger. They can either take turns and wait for each other or they can work on separate classes which are called from logic less trigger without worrying what changes trigger is going to make to their input.